# How to upload video files on cdn server?

Tags: php, file, upload, cdn

I am trying to upload video on cdn server(hwcdn.net server) through api, but getting the following error .
" **0470 Invalid file name (A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_,',.)** "

```
//PHP example code for calling an action: 
$action = "UF"; //get system info 
$user = "xxxxxx"; //my StrikeTracker user name 
$pass = "xxxxxx"; //my StrikeTracker password 
$apiKey ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //my API Key
$md5pass = md5($pass); 
$queryString = "action=$action&user=$user&key=$apiKey&password=$md5pass"; 
$token =md5($queryString); 
$directory="/folder path/";
$Filedata="testingvideo.flv";
echo $apiQuery = "action=$action&user=$user&token=$token&directory=$directory&Filedata=$Filedata";  
$host="http://st-api.hwcdn.net/index.php";

echo do_post_request($host,$apiQuery);

function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }

  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think this is wrong :**

```
$directory="/folder path/";
```

The space is not allowed in `hwcdn` paths.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error: the filename contains illegal chars, you have to sanitize it removing everything that is not `A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_,',.`.

You can use `preg_replace`.

Comment: My filename is testingvideo.flv, what's wrong in this filename.